Rust reqwest proxy server dependency issues when using with another library
I have a proxy server using actix-web that it works pretty well. An encoding problem start happening when I install another dependency library rusty_ytdl, and then the proxy server starts returning an error error decoding response body. I assume this is because rusty_ytdl has some specific features for the reqwest dependency:
[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.12.7", features = [
    "cookies",
    "gzip",
] }

EDIT: To narrow down the issue. When I am using the dependency reqwest = "0.12.7" proxy server works, but when I am using reqwest = { version = "0.12.7", features = [<even all features here>] } it doesn't work, both with default-features = false and default-features = true.
If I fork the library and change the features, rusty_ytdl stops working due to missing cookies feature. It does not throw an error, but it fails with a 403 and drops the stream chunks after a while when downloading.
I suspect that the encoding that the actix-web server fails to decode is brotli, but whatever I tried to include even all the reqwest features does not work, either the proxy works or rusty_ytdl.
I tried this on my library and it does not work, proxy keeps failing to decode responses:
reqwest = { version = "0.12.7", features = [
  "charset",
  "cookies",
  "gzip",
  "brotli",
  "zstd",
  "deflate",
] }


Is this a dependency issue or something deeper?
How can I solve this issue and have both actix-web proxy and rusty_ytdl working?
Can I manually handle decoding requests for the actix-web Client responses?

Here is the proxy server code:
mod.rs
mod handlers;

use std::sync::Mutex;
use actix_web::{middleware, web, App, HttpServer};
use tauri::{AppHandle, Manager};

use crate::AppState;

#[actix_web::main]
pub async fn init(app: AppHandle) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    env_logger::init();

    let srv = HttpServer::new(move || {

        let app = App::new()
            .wrap(middleware::Compress::default()) // Always apply Compress
            .default_service(web::route().to(handlers::proxy));

        // Apply Logger only in dev builds
        #[cfg(debug_assertions)]
        let app = app.wrap(middleware::Logger::default());

        app
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", 0))?;

    let port = srv.addrs()[0].port();
    println!("Server is running on port {}", port);

    srv.run().await
}

handlers.rs
use awc::{Client, Connector};
use actix_web::{http::header, web, HttpRequest, HttpResponse};
use futures_util::{StreamExt};
use std::{collections::HashMap, time::Duration};
use openssl::ssl::{SslConnector, SslMethod};
use url::Url;
use inline_colorization::*;

pub async fn proxy(req: HttpRequest, mut payload: web::Payload) -> HttpResponse {
    if req.method() == "OPTIONS" {
        return HttpResponse::Ok()
            .insert_header((
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
                req.headers()
                    .get("origin")
                    .unwrap_or(&header::HeaderValue::from_static("*"))
                    .clone(),
            ))
            .insert_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*"))
            .insert_header(("User-Agent", "..."))
            .insert_header((
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
                "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, x-goog-visitor-id, x-origin, x-youtube-client-version, x-youtube-client-name, x-goog-api-format-version, x-user-agent, Accept-Language, Range, Referer",
            ))
            .insert_header(("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400"))
            .insert_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"))
            .finish();
    }

    let query = req.query_string();
    let query_params: HashMap<_, _> =
        url::form_urlencoded::parse(query.as_bytes()).into_owned().collect();

    if !query_params.contains_key("__host") {
        return HttpResponse::BadRequest()
            .body("Request is formatted incorrectly. Please include __host in the query string.");
    }

    let mut url = format!(
        "https://{}{}",
        query_params["__host"],
        req.uri().path()
    );

    if let Some(query) = req.uri().query() {
        let query_without_host = query
            .split('&')
            .filter(|kv| !kv.starts_with("__host") && !kv.starts_with("__headers"))
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>()
            .join("&");
        if !query_without_host.is_empty() {
            url = format!("{}?{}", url, query_without_host);
        }
    }

    println!("{color_yellow}Proxying request to URL: {}{color_reset}", url);

    // Create an SSL connector that ignores certificate verification
    let mut ssl_connector_builder = SslConnector::builder(SslMethod::tls()).unwrap();
    ssl_connector_builder.set_verify(openssl::ssl::SslVerifyMode::NONE);
    let ssl_connector = ssl_connector_builder.build();

    // // Create a Connector using the SSL connector
    let connector = Connector::new().openssl(ssl_connector);

    let client = Client::builder()
        .connector(connector)
        .timeout(Duration::from_secs(30))
        .finish();

    let mut client_req = client.request(req.method().clone(), url.clone());

    // Manually forward headers from the original request
    for (key, value) in req.headers().iter() {
        client_req = client_req.append_header((key.clone(), value.clone()));
    }

    // Set the Host header to the proxied URL host
    let host = Url::parse(&url).unwrap().host().unwrap().to_string();
    client_req = client_req.insert_header(("Host", host));


    client_req = client_req
        .insert_header(("User-Agent", "..."));

    // Handle request body based on the method
    let response = if req.method() == "POST" || req.method() == "PUT" || req.method() == "PATCH" {
        let mut body = web::BytesMut::new();
        while let Some(chunk) = payload.next().await {
            if let Ok(chunk) = chunk {
                body.extend_from_slice(&chunk);
            } else {
                return HttpResponse::BadRequest().body("Error reading request body");
            }
        }

        client_req.send_body(body.freeze()).await
    } else {
        client_req.send().await
    };

    let response = match response {
        Ok(res) => res,
        Err(e) => {
            println!("{color_red}Error while sending request to upstream server: {:?}{color_reset}", e);
            return HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish();
        }
    };

    let mut res_builder = HttpResponse::build(response.status());
    for (key, value) in response.headers().iter() {
        println!("{color_cyan}response header: {}: {:?}{color_reset}", key, value);
        res_builder.insert_header((key.clone(), value.clone()));
    }

    res_builder
        .insert_header((
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
            req.headers()
                .get("origin")
                .unwrap_or(&header::HeaderValue::from_static("*"))
                .clone(),
        ))
        .insert_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"))
        .insert_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*"))
        .insert_header(("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));

    res_builder.streaming(response)
}

